# Automate button clicks and upload on a website, creating a "robot" to perform manual process on a website

Tags: automation, web-crawler

Every day, I have to go to an intranet website and click a series of buttons, upload an excel file to this website, and select an option from a drop down box. I am familiar with programming and am wondering what type of code or program can help us automate this daily process since it takes about 20 minutes to do this process every day.

I'm thinking that this is the same type of thing that "robots" do to create spam accounts on sites like Google, hence the need for captcha.

What do I need to know to get started on this or learn how to automate this process? We use Internet Explorer to view this intranet website service. I don't even know what this process is called or where I can find a tutorial on this.

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, the process involves loging into a system with a username and password, clicking a button, navigating to a link, uploading a file, waiting 10 minutes, then navigating to another page, entering a password, clicking another button, and then it's done.

EDIT 2: There is no captcha, but I'm trying to learn the easiest way to go through a process similar to the way a programmer would go about clicking through links, entering data into forms, etc. like a spam account creator would, only this is for legitimate internal business processes with no captcha involved.

Comment: have a look at selenium rc, there is an add on selenium ide for firefox that will record user interaction and then run the saved test. or if using chrome - imacros does a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Internet Explorer with VBScript; it's not what I would call a pleasant process, but in my experience it can be made to work quite well.

Consider the following script which automates a website login, half-inched from [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/vbscript/72327-using-vbscript-fill-out-web-form.html):

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
IE.Navigate "http://mylogin.page" 
IE.Visible = True 
Wscript.Sleep 6000 
IE.Document.All.Item("fld_userName").Value = "adley" 
IE.Document.All.Item("fld_password").Value = "password" 
WshShell.AppActivate "IE" 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

The only part I can see being really tricky would be choosing the file to upload; for security reasons, it may not be possible to script an `<input type="file">` control this way -- of course, this being Internet Explorer, I suspect it'll work just fine.

It's been so long since I did anything like this that I can no longer find real documentation on it, but a good place to start would be [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+ie+automation); most of what you're doing is just filling and POSTing forms and following links, from the look of your question, and probably won't be all that hard to do by just grabbing bits here and there and modifying them to suit your situation.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure from your question whether there's a captcha on the form you're looking to automate. If so, you will certainly need to complete it by hand; even in that case, though, automating the process of reaching and filling that form should save you considerable time on a daily basis.